# Set .ipa release notes / version information before submitting to iTunes Connect: Test Flight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

How do you set the release notes for a build on iTunes Connect Test Flight before submitting to iTunes Connect?

I'm aware that you can manually set the details by clicking on the build number inside of iTunes Connect, after the build has been uploaded. However, at that point, if you haven't changed the version, the build is automatically released without version information (What to test / App Description).

How do you set this information in the compile / export / upload process? I'm using Xcode 6 to compile and export and Application Loader to upload to iTC.

Comment: Did you add the new app version in ITC? Fill in all of the details before you upload the binary.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm specifically talking about Test Flight. I'm assuming that the details will need to be filled in inside of Xcode.